# Woocommerce Api: Store Category with image get error Bad Request 400

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, woocommerce

I am using Laravel 8 with woocommerce api's. I am creatng Product Category using Woocomerce api's documentation.

```
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product-category
```

and I am sending request to upload images like this,

```
$categoryPhotoUrl = null;
    if (request()->hasFile('images')) {
        $file = $request->file('images') ;
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/assets/images/categories' ;
        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
        $categoryPhotoUrl = asset('/assets/images/categories').'/'.$fileName;
    }

    $request->request->add(['image' => ['src' => $categoryPhotoUrl]]);
    CategoryService::created($request->except('_token', 'images'));
```

and in Service class i am using logic,

```
public static function created($data)
{
    return (new WoocommerceClient())->postRecord('products/categories',$data);
}
```

and WoocommerceClient contain this logic,

```
$response =  Http::withToken($this->authToken)->withHeaders([
        "Content-Type" => "image/jpg"
    ])->post($this->baseUrl.$endpoint, $data);
    dd($response);
```

If i send data without image its working fine but If I store image then send url i received error Bad Request 400.

```
    Illuminate\Http\Client\Response {#279 ▼
    #response: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#314 ▼
    -reasonPhrase: "Bad Request"
    -statusCode: 400
    -headers: array:20 [▶]
    -headerNames: array:20 [▶]
    -protocol: "1.1"
    -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#313 ▶}
   }
```

How can i solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With alot of search i will be able to fix it. I have use fetch to uplaoad image on wordpress database. Then i get object it contain source url then i send it using woocommerce